# What is the significance of #pragma marks? Why do we need #pragma marks?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, comments, pragma

What is the purpose of `#pragma` marks in Xcode? Does their location in `.m` files matter? Should some `#pragma` come before all others?

- Do they have to be present?
- Can new marks be added? Why would they be? What causes it?
- Is there any harm in having a mark removed? Would one ever want to?

Comment: Check the link: http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2006/09/tip-pragma-mark-organizing-your-source.html

Comment: I personally don't like them. Seriously, you want to think about where you have to put a method all the time? There are far more important things to keep organized, like paying attention to the Single Responsibility Principle

Comment: For swift language #Pragma mark won't work. Use #MARK or #FIXME  or #TODO check this link for more info http://stackoverflow.com/a/33040068/1753005

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36953187/443530

Comment: Is it the literal `#pragma mark`?

Answer (score 323):

`#pragma mark` directives show up in Xcode in the menus for direct access to methods. They have no impact on the program at all.

For example, using it with Xcode 4 will make those items appear directly in the Jump Bar.

There is a special `pragma mark -` which creates a line.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the answer--would you be able to post an updated answer showing what pragma marks look like (in that menu or wherever they are now) in the new XCode?

Comment: Is there a Python equivalent?

Comment: @EdwardFalk It's IDE specific, so it really depends on your IDE / text editor

Comment: My GCC compiler gave the warning, foo.h:52:0: warning: ignoring #pragma mark  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma mark -, which is not fatal.  So gcc probably does not know about '-'.

Comment: I'm not expecting this comment to be noticed or to change the ranking of previous answers... But the OP was clearly, IMO, asking about `#pragma` statements in general, not just the specific `#pragma mark` directive. While a better choice of words, e.g. using statement or directive instead of mark would help, his use of `code` highlighting makes this clear. @Maxim Chetrusca provides an answer below that addresses this interpretation of the OP.

Answer (score 56):

`#pragma mark` is used to tag the group of methods so you may easily find and detect methods from the Jump Bar. It may help you when your code files reach about 1000 lines and you want to find methods quickly through the category from the Jump box.

In a long program it becomes difficult to remember and find a method name. So **pragma mark** allows you to categorize methods according to the work they do. For example, you tagged some tag for Table View Protocol Methods, AlertView Methods, Init Methods, Declaration, etc.

`#pragma mark` is the facility for Xcode, but it has no impact on your code. It merely helps to make it easier to find methods while coding.

Answer (score 22):

In simple words, we can say that `#pragma mark -` is used for categorizing methods, so you can find your methods easily. It is very useful for long projects.

Answer (score 16):

Just to add the information I was looking for: `pragma mark` is Xcode specific, so if you deal with a C++ project that you open in different IDEs, it does not have any effect there. In [Qt Creator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator), for example, it does not add categories for methods, nor generate any warnings/errors.

`#pragma` is a preprocessor directive which comes from C programming language. Its purpose is to specify implementation-dependent information to the compiler - that is, each compiler might choose to interpret this directive as it wants. That said, it is rather considered an extension which does not change/influence the code itself. So compilers might as well ignore it.

Xcode is an IDE which takes advantage of `#pragma` and uses it in its own specific way. The point is, `#pragma` is not Xcode and even Objective-C specific.

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
#pragma mark - NSSecureCoding
```

The main purpose of "pragma" is for developer reference.

[image]

You can easily find a method/function in a vast thousands of coding lines.

**Xcode 11+:**

Marker Line in Top

```
// MARK: - Properties
```

Marker Line in Top and Bottom

```
// MARK: - Properties -
```

Marker Line only in bottom

```
// MARK: Properties -
```

Comment: So i can remove the line? its waste of space for my brain.

Comment: Removing **#pragma-mark** wont affect any functionality of your code, but your code may lose its readability. If you really don't want ,you can remove it.

Answer (score 11):

When we have a big/lengthy class, say more than a couple of 100s lines of code, we can't see everything on the monitor screen, hence we can't see the overview (also called document items) of our class. Sometime we want to see the overview of our class; all its methods, constants, properties, etc. at a glance. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> in Xcode to see overview of your class. You'll get a pop-up kind of window aka Jump Bar.

By default, this jump bar doesn't have any buckets/sections. It's just one long list. (Though we can just start typing when jump Bar appears and it will search among jump bar items.) Here comes the need of `pragma mark`.

If you want to create sections in your Jump Bar then you can use pragma marks with relevant description. Now refer to the snapshot attached in the question. There 'View lifeCycle' and 'A section dedicated ..' are sections created by `pragma mark`s.