# Is it possible to have a "#pragma mark" hierarchy?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, categories, pragma

I use `#pragma mark - Description` frequently to organize my methods in Xcode. However, I find that sometimes I need to categories and subcategories for my methods, like this:

> - Public Methods
>
>   - Helper Methods
>
>     - aMethod
>   - Other Type of Methods
>
>     - anotherMethod
> - Private Methods
>
>   - Some Type of Method
>
>     - aPrivateMethod

Is this possible?

Comment: Any code that needs this should be simplified.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Simply only use the `-` before and after your main section to surround it in lines, exclude the dash for the subsections, and then the method names will show as always.

```
#pragma mark - Public Methods -
#pragma mark Helper Methods
- (void)aMethod{}
#pragma mark Other Type of Methods
- (void)anotherMethod{}

#pragma mark - Private Methods -
#pragma mark Some Type of Method
- (void)aPrivateMethod{}
```

---

[image]

Comment: I preferred the way this worked in Xcode 3, where those same pragmas would actually show a hierarchy.

Comment: For some reason Xcode 4.5.1 would not show the first `#pragma` until a method was defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of these combinations:

1. Hyphen before `Description` - Puts a separator above the description

`#pragma mark - Description`

2. Hyphen after `Description` - Puts a separator below the description

`#pragma mark Description -`

3. Hyphen before and after `Description` - Puts a separator above and below the description

`#pragma mark - Description -`

[image: screenshot]

Also, if you just want separators and no descriptions, simply use `#pragma mark` or `#pragma mark -`.