# What is the equivalent of "#pragma mark -" in swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I want to organize my code by sections. usually I used `#pragma mark - Section Name`
but when I try to do so in a .swift file it doesn't work.

So my question is if I can somehow enable it and if not what is the way to organize my code in sections in a .swift file?

Comment: yes but I want to separate for example the uitableview delegate from the uttableview datasource and if i'll make a class for each section ill get more classes then i can handle

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use something like that:

```
// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
```

Or use `extensions`: I love the way how `UITableViewDataSource` delegate is implemented [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017316/pragma-mark-in-swift)

Comment: You meant this answer right http://stackoverflow.com/a/24069206/366346 ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d  yes, this one

Comment: You can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/33040068/1753005