# Annotating Swift function declarations that support conformance to a protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift2, swift-protocols

Is there a standard mechanism for annotating function declarations in Swift to indicate that they are present because a class conforms to some protocol?

For instance, this declaration might be present because a class conforms to `NSCoding`. (Marking it with `override` would result in a syntax error, so it's not the kind of annotation I am looking for.) Ideally I am looking for a code-level annotation (e.g. `override` instead of `/*! ... */`).

```
// ... annotation such as "conform to NSCoding", if possible
func encodeWithCoder(encoder: NSCoder) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Annotating in a comment, or in the code?

Comment: @Aderstedt Annotating in the code would be best (see update to Q).

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to annotate protocol conformance in the code. Use comments.

Comment: @robertvojta Too bad. (I am using comments now but wish for an alternative.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`extension`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID277). for example:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func doIt() -> Int
}


class ConcreteClass {
    ....
}

extension ConcreteClass: SomeProtocol {
    func doIt() -> Int {
       // ...
       return 1
    }
}
```

But you cannot define `required` initializer in `extension`, for example:

```
// THIS DOES NOT WORK!!!

class Foo: NSObject {
}
extension Foo: NSCoding {
    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

emits an error:

```
error: 'required' initializer must be declared directly in class 'Foo' (not in an extension)
    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    ~~~~~~~~             ^
```

In this case, you should use [`// MARK:` comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24017316/3804019):

```
class Foo: NSObject {

    // ...


    // MARK: NSCoding

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init()
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        // ... 
    }
}
```