# Pragma mark in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How can I mark my code with pragma as we have used in objective c

Comment: You can make extension of controller.

Comment: @Raj Aggrawal : you can accept my answer if it is helpful. Thanks

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33040068/1753005

Answer (score 7):

Use `// MARK: -`, for example:

```
// MARK: - tableview delegate methods
```