# PhpStorm / PyCharm Structure sidebar markers using comments?

Tags: pycharm, ide, phpstorm, comments

Is it possible to add some kind of comment marker in the code which can group or separate blocks in the structure view?

This isn't very helpful:

[image: Unhelpful structure]

I was hoping for something similar to the pragma mark feature in XCode (like [#pragma mark in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017316/pragma-mark-in-swift))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same behavior / act as a plain separator -- nope.
Grouping -- yes.

```scss
//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="YOUR TEXT HERE">
...CSS CODE HERE...
//</editor-fold>
```

An example:

```scss
//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Misc global things">
.main-container .main-wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
//</editor-fold>

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Video embedding">
.embed-video {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  &::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
  }
  > iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
  }
}
.embed-video-16x9::after {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}
//</editor-fold>
```

[image]

You can also make them nested if needed (I personally have no need for this though; and never even tried more than one level deep).

HINT: you can use dashes or similar symbols to make it a bit more visible/standing out (distinguish from the actual styles):

```scss
//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="=== My First Block">
.main-container .main-wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
//</editor-fold>

//<editor-fold desc="=== My Second Block">
.main-container .main-wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
//</editor-fold>
```

[image]

[image]

---

##### NOTES:

1. `region`...`endregion` style of comment will also work. It is simpler to write & read (since it's not a XML-like tag).

   Cons: you cannot provide the default state (collapsed or expanded) this way.

   ```scss
   //region My First Block
   .main-container .main-wrapper {
     padding-bottom: 0;
   }
   //endregion

   //region My Second Block
   .main-container .main-wrapper {
     padding-bottom: 0;
   }
   //endregion
   ```
2. You cannot mix multiple comment styles in the same file.

   I mean: you can... but the first style found in a file will be treated as a grouping comment; another style will be treated as an ordinary plain comment.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-source-code.html#use-the-surround-with-action