# How to view the list of all variables and methods in a class in Xcode while coding (not debugging) like in Eclipse?

Tags: objective-c, eclipse, xcode

Is there a way to view a list of all variables and methods in a class like in Eclipse, where all variables and methods of the class are listed vertically on the right side of the window. This Eclipse feature is useful to quickly see all the members of a class and you can click them to jump to their definitions.

Googling for this question led me to a lot of stuff about finding variable values when debugging, which I already know how to do and is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: use pragmas for this check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853821/what-is-the-significance-of-pragma-marks-why-do-we-need-pragma-marks

Comment: it seems like this is the best (and only) answer here. pragmas are not as helpful as the Eclipse list though, since you have to click on the Jump Bar to see the list. please move your response to the answer section instead of the comments section to be accepted as the answer.

Comment: ok will do that in a moment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pragmas for this.

`#pragma mark directives show up in XCode in the menus for direct access to methods.`

Using them allows them to appear directly in the jump bar.

Also check out the answer to the question here.

[What is the significance of #pragma marks? Why do we need #pragma marks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853821/what-is-the-significance-of-pragma-marks-why-do-we-need-pragma-marks)

Comment: I explored Xcode some more and the Symbol Navigator on the left side of the screen is a really good place to find what I was looking for.